# Mellin inversion and the entire function $\varphi(s)=\frac{1-e^{2s}}{e^{-s}-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence, complex-integration, analyticity, mellin-transform

I would like to learn to calculate inverse Mellin tranforms. My example (!) is for the following **entire function** $$\varphi(s)=\frac{1-e^{2s}}{e^{-s}-1},$$ (see if you want the Wikipedia's entry for the Faulhaber's formula) where $s=\sigma+it$ is our **complex varible**.

**Wikipedia's** article for [Mellin inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_inversion_theorem) is saying to me that is required some conditions with the purpose to apply the **Method** for my analytic function (if it is possible for the example (!) that I am exploring:  that is if our function satisfies such conditions in this inversion theorem).

> **Question.** It's possible to apply the **Method** explained to the function $\varphi(s)$ in a strip? **Many thanks.**

I believe that $\varphi(s)=\frac{1-e^{2s}}{e^{-s}-1}$ doesn't tend to zero uniformly as $\Im s\to\pm\infty$, but currently I don't know how do a mathematical reasoning (I believe that the supremum of the complex modulus is bounded in each strip independently of the imaginary part), thus I believe that it is not possible apply the Method. What are the conditions that fail?

Comment: Why don't you simplify $\varphi(s)$ to $e^{2s} + e^s$?

Comment: I did not see that, then I am saying thanks to you and user1952009, and sorry for my question. Thanks for your early responses. I want start to learn this methods @RobertIsrael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$1-e^{2s} = (1-e^s)(1+e^{s})$ thus $$\varphi(s) = e^s \frac{1-e^{2s}}{1-e^s} = e^s(1+e^s) = e^s + e^{2s}$$ and it is the Mellin transform of the (tempered) distribution $$T(x)  = e\, \delta(x-e)+e^2\,\delta(x-e^2)$$
i.e. $\varphi(s) = \int_0^\infty x^{s-1}T(x)dx$
And the procedure for computing the inverse Mellin transform of the Mellin transform of a (tempered) distribution is more complicated than a contour integral. You should look instead at the Fourier transform of Schwartz functions and tempered distributions.

Comment: It was very quick! Now I try understand your good calculations. Many thanks. I start with this calculations, I will continue to ask about complex integration (Laplace, Fourier and Mellin) in this site. Thanks one more time.

Comment: @user1952009 Concise and clear!  +1